# R plotly scatterpolar chart bubble missing

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I know it must be basic thing but had hard time finding the issue.
Here is my easy **reproducible R code**:

```
library(plotly)

risk_status <- data.frame(
  id <- c(1:6),
  r <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2),
  theta <- c(30, 90, 180, 220, 270, 330),
  bubbleSize <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
  name <- c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary", "Pedro"),
  status <- c("Low", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low")
)

risk_status$status <- factor(risk_status$status, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))
bubble_colors_vector <- c("red", "green", "blue")


p <- plot_ly( data = risk_register_data) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    r = ~r,
    theta = ~theta,
    size = as.numeric(risk_status$status),
    sizes = c(100,500)#,

    #color = risk_status$status,
    #colors = bubble_colors_vector
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scatterpolar",
    mode = "text",
    r = risk_status$r,
    theta = risk_status$theta,
    text = risk_status$id

  )
p
```

**Chart output:**

[image]

So far, it's good.
But now lets say, If I want to introduce color in it, just by uncommenting `color` and `colors` parameters.
I get this chart:

[image]

Let's say if I use `color = as.numeric(risk_status$status)`
In that case, I get chart something like this
[image]

Here, I don't want this scales and legends.

I know, there is some issue because while `factoring` the `status` column of dataframe, I have provided `"Low", "Medium", "High"` as levels, while in column only `"Low", "Medium"` is present. 
But, this is a normal case, also, without color the size of the bubbles are represented correctly, then why while adding color there are missing sizes too ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, 
I resolved the issue through a workaround of using `add_trace` inside `for loop`.

**Here is the code:**

```
library(plotly)

risk_status <- data.frame(
  id <- c(1:6),
  r <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2),
  theta <- c(30, 90, 180, 220, 270, 330),
  bubbleSize <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
  name <- c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary", "Pedro"),
  status <- c("Low", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low")
)

risk_status$status <- factor(risk_status$status, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))
bubble_colors_vector <- c("red", "green", "blue")


p <- plot_ly( data = risk_status) %>%

  add_trace(
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    r = risk_status$r[risk_status$status == 'Low'],
    theta = risk_status$theta[risk_status$status == 'Low'],
    #size = as.numeric(risk_status$status[risk_status$status == 'Low']),
    #sizes = c(100,500),

    #color = 'red', #risk_status$status[risk_status$status == 'Low'], #as.numeric(risk_status$status), #risk_status$status,
    #colors = bubble_colors_vector[risk_status$status == 'Low'],

    mode = 'markers',
    marker = list(symbol = 'circle', line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'), mode="scatterpolar", color = "red", size=20)
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    r = risk_status$r[risk_status$status == 'Medium'],
    theta = risk_status$theta[risk_status$status == 'Medium'],
    #size = as.numeric(risk_status$status[risk_status$status == 'Medium']),
    #sizes = c(100,500),

    #color = 'red', #risk_status$status[risk_status$status == 'Medium'], #as.numeric(risk_status$status), #risk_status$status,
    #colors = bubble_colors_vector[risk_status$status == 'Medium'],

    mode = 'markers',
    marker = list(symbol = 'circle', line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'), mode="scatterpolar", color = "yellow", size=20)
  ) %>%

  add_trace(
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    r = risk_status$r[risk_status$status == 'High'],
    theta = risk_status$theta[risk_status$status == 'High'],
    #size = as.numeric(risk_status$status[risk_status$status == 'High']),
    #sizes = c(100,500),

    #color = 'red', #risk_status$status[risk_status$status == 'High'], #as.numeric(risk_status$status), #risk_status$status,
    #colors = bubble_colors_vector[risk_status$status == 'High'],

    mode = 'markers',
    marker = list(symbol = 'circle', line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'), mode="scatterpolar", color = "green", size=20)
  ) %>%


  add_trace(
    type = "scatterpolar",
    mode = "text",
    r = risk_status$r,
    theta = risk_status$theta,
    text = risk_status$id

  )
p
```

Output Chart:
[image]